# Augmented nonlinear state space model for nonlinear model predictive control?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Assume that we have a discrete state space model:

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k)\\ y(k) = Cx(k) + Du(k)$$

And we want to use optimization to minimize this cost function.

$$J =\sum_{k=0}^{n}(x_k^TQx_k + u_k^TRu_k)$$

Where the states $x_k$ can be found from the augmented state space model.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_0\\ 
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3\\ 
\vdots\\ 
x_{n}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
A\\ 
A^2\\ 
A^3\\ 
A^4\\ 
\vdots\\ 
A^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}x_0+\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\ 
AB & B & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\ 
A^2B & AB & B & 0 & \dots& 0\\ 
A^3B & A^2B & AB & B & \dots& 0\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots  &\ddots & 0\\ 
A^{n-2}B & A^{n-3}B & A^{n-4}B & A^{n-5}B  & \dots & B 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
u_0\\ 
u_1\\ 
u_2\\ 
u_3\\ 
\vdots\\ 
u_n
\end{bmatrix}$$

But what if I have a nonlinear state space model:

$$x(k+1) = A(x(k), u(k)) + B(x(k), u(k))\\ y(k) = C(x(k), u(k)) + D(x(k), u(k))$$

How can I create the augmented state space model, if I want a perfect linearization?

Because, when I linearize a state space model:

$$\dot x = f(x, u)$$

I need to linezarise the model in (0,0) by using first talyor series.

$$f_L(x,a) = f(a) +  \dot f(a,u) (x-a)$$

Where $f(a) = 0$ and $\delta = (x-a)$

So the new linear state space model will be:

$$\dot x \delta = Ax\delta + B u\delta$$

Where $A = \dot f(a,u)$.

But what if I not use first taylor series? How can I then create the nonlinear augmented state space model?

Can I create the nonlinear augmented state space model like this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_0\\ 
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3\\ 
\vdots\\ 
x_{n}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\bar A\\ 
\bar A^2\\ 
\bar A^3\\ 
\bar A^4\\ 
\vdots\\ 
\bar A^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\ 
AB & B & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\ 
A^2B & AB & B & 0 & \dots& 0\\ 
A^3B & A^2B & AB & B & \dots& 0\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots  &\ddots & 0\\ 
A^{n-2}B & A^{n-3}B & A^{n-4}B & A^{n-5}B  & \dots & B 
\end{bmatrix} $$

Where $$\bar A = A(x(k_0), u(k))$$  $$A = A(x(k_0), u(k))$$ $$B =  B(x(k_0), u(k))$$

?

Comment: Are you asking what the nonlinear prediction model is in a discrete-time representation of an optimal control problem that really wants to address an underlying continuous-time process?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Yes. I asking about the discrete time representation, but the linearizing is different. Well, first it need to be a continuous time representation model, then it need to be linearize and then turn to discrete time. The linearizion is the question here. Can I turn the continuous time model to discrete without to linearize the system without first taylor series/jacobian?

Comment: For the nonlinear state-space model $\dot{x}(t) = f(x(t),u(t))$, the discret-time nonlinear model, under zero-hold input assumption, is given by $x(t+T) = \int_{t}^{t+T}f(x(\tau,u(t))d\tau$, i.e., no simple formula if that is what you are looking for. If you linearize $f$ (around which input?...) you get the standard $e^{AT}$ expressions etc

Comment: @JohanLöfberg So nonlinear prediction is far more difficult that it sounds like? Maybe I should stay at linear prediction instead....

Comment: Yes, basically you first have to integrate the dynamics along a predicted path (which means you have to have an initial guess of input), then linearize the dynamics at each sample along the path, and then discretize. You essentially have to implement a general optimal control solver if you want to do it correctly

Comment: Ok. When is nonlinear prediction needed in reality? Is adaptive mpc the only well worked mpc for nonlinear systems?

Comment: Nonlinear predictions are needed when linear aren't enough. A non-answer, but impossible to specify better.

Comment: I added more text in my question. About adaptive mpc. You have probably been working with what?

Comment: Nope. But I would say that's a completely different thing

Comment: Ok. No adaptive control at all? As I have heard, adaptive controllers needs to have stochastic input signals from the measurements. Or else adaptive controllers will estimate a static model, which will cause instability.

Comment: That was a somewhat strong claim, but persistently exciting signals, identifiability, direct vs indirect adaptive control etc is a way too massive topic for a comment here

Comment: OK. Thank you anyway.